# convert from one bech32 address to another with different slip44 coinTypes

Tags: encryption, public-key

I would like convert between one bech32 address to another with different [slip44 coinTypes](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md).

For example, a `terra` address `terra172xqaafhz6djy448p32633q4rl7eaz4wqnjn46` uses slip44=330 and `cosmos` address `cosmos1mwwvfu804wcaanz8j78f8h75flxkyjua23kdvw` uses slip44=118.

The prefixes can be assume to be the first characters til you find a `1`, and thus can be popped off easily, leaving us with the bech32 string.

assuming only `coin_type` changes in the HD wallet path (`m / 44' / coin_type' / account' / change / address`), is it possible to derive one from the other?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about cryptography.

Comment: where would you suggest asking this question? It may involve deriving the public key from the bech32, which could be a solution to this question.

Comment: @pyramation: I have no idea about what bech32 and slip44 are, but if these are any related to bitcoin (resp. etherum) , there's [bitcoin-se](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) (resp. [etherum-se](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/)). Here on crypto-se, when it comes to cryptocurrencies, only strictly cryptographic aspects are on-topic, and then we'd rather avoid what's specific to a particular system, especially it's arbitrary conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> assuming only coin_type changes in the HD wallet path (m / 44' / coin_type' / account' / change / address), is it possible to derive one from the other?

No. It is not possible to learn about any other parent or sibling keys using HD without more information.

The bech32 encoding is completely unrelated.